# IDBDatabase Transaction Error not being handled

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, indexeddb

I'm trying to build a generic IndexedDB Module to be used across multiple projects. I've come across some strange behavior that I can't figure out.

From my understanding, there are only 3 events that can happen with a transaction, however, neither the abort or error event are being executed when I purposefully apply a bad objectStore.

I'm confused if it's something I've setup incorrectly or this is intended behavior, thanks for taking the time to look at my question!

```
/**
 * Adds a single object to the specificed objectStore
 * @param {IDBDatabase} database Initiliazed database
 * @param {string} objectStore Name of objectStore where transactions will be occurring
 * @param {object} data Object to be inserted into the objectStore
 * @returns {Promise} Resolve => String | Reject => Error
 */
async function addRecord(database, storeName, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");

            transaction.oncomplete = function () {
                console.log("Add Transaction Successful.");
            };

            transaction.onabort = function (event) {
                throw (`Transaction Aborted - Supplied Data {${database},${storeName},${data}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
            }

            transaction.onerror = function (event) {
                throw (`Transaction Failed - Supplied Data {${database},${storeName},${data}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
            };

            let objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);

            let request = objectStore.add(data);

            request.onsuccess = function () {
                console.log("Add Request Succesful");
                resolve()
            };

            request.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log(`Request Failed: addRecord - Supplied Data {${database_name},${database_version},${upgrade_function}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
                throw (`Request Failed: Supplied Data {${database_name},${database_version},${upgrade_function}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
            };

        } catch (error) {
            reject(`Error: AddRecord - ${error.message}`)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. resolve the promise when the transaction completes, not when the request completes.
2. reject when the transaction errors, not when the request errors. basically get rid of your request onsuccess/onerror, or use them only to log to console and nothing else.
3. do not use try catch, catch won't always catch the errors you expect here, it is basically pointless
4. do not use the async qualifier, you are not awaiting anything, this makes no sense
5. you should really take a step back and go learn about asynchronous programming, this is the source of your frustration, but this is not a short thing to describe in a basic answer, it can sometimes take a 100 page book to explain it

Based on your comment, try this:

```js
function connect(name, version, onupgradeneeded) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
    request.onsuccess = event => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = event => reject(request.error);
    request.onupgradeneeded = onupgradeneeded;
  });
}

function addRecord(database, storeName, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    transaction.oncomplete = resolve;
    transaction.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    transaction.objectStore(storeName).add(data);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const db = await connect('mydb', 1);
  console.log('connected');
  try {
    await addRecord(db, 'things', { foo: 'bar' });
    console.log('added record');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore the comment above, missed my shift key

3 -> Do you have a recommendation for an alternative? My thought was use it as a way of wrapping all errors into a specific format to be rejected with detailed debugging. It might just be bad practice, it was the first method that came to mind.

4 -> The IndexedDB is an Async API,  so I thought It'd make sense to tag them as async and return a promise so I can resolve it so I could extract the data.